# How to test angularjs resource with injected constant

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am struggling with writing some tests for RESTful resource. I'm new to the frameworks, so please adjust your explanation accordingly.

I am using angular-mocks + Karma-Jasmine for unit testing. And here is the REST resource test object:

```
   angular.module('resources', ['ngResource'])
     .factory('Login', function($resource, helpers) {
       return $resource(
         helpers.getApiUrl() + 'login'
       );
     })
```

helpers is a constant defined in another module:

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'filters', 'services', 'resources']).constant('helpers', {
  getLanguage                 : function() { return angular.element('meta[http-equiv]').attr('content'); },
  getApiUrl                   : function() { return '<%= @site.config[:api] %>'.replace(/\%\{lang\}/,this.getLanguage() + '.'); }
}).config(['$routeProvider', '$anchorScrollProvider', 'helpers', config]).run(runner)
```

And finally, here's the problematic unit test:

```
describe("Resources test suite", function() {

  var mockHelpers;

  beforeEach(function(){
    mockHelpers = sinon.stub({ getLanguage: function() {return 'de';}, getApiUrl: function(){ return 'http://testApiUrl/';} });
    module('app', function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('helpers', mockHelpers);
    })
  });

  beforeEach(module('resources')); 

  describe('Login resource', function() {

    it('should send a post resquest to /login', inject(function(Login, $httpBackend, helpers){
      var   url = 'http://testApiUrl/login',
            data = 'mock data',
            headers = {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
            successCallback = jasmine.createSpy('success'),
            errorCallback = jasmine.createSpy('error');
      $httpBackend.expectPOST(url, data, headers).respond(200, {token:'Oh yeah!'});
      var answer = Login.save(data);
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(answer.token).toBe('Oh yeah!');
      expect(errorCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    }))

  })

});
```

The test is failing and I have no idea why. It seems that the mock getApiUrl function isn't defined (here the console output from karma):

```
Chrome 34.0.1847 (Linux) Resources test suite Login resource should send a post resquest to /login FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: POST undefinedlogin
    Expected POST http://testApiUrl/login
```

I am stuck here. Does someone have an idea what might be going wrong? I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, I found that the problem is in the sinon

Comment: OK, as it seems, the sinon stub was not doing what I expected. If anyone can explain why, that would be great. The test passes now:   beforeEach( function () {
    mockHelpers = { getApiUrl: function(){ return 'http://testApiUrl/';} };
    module('app' , function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('helpers', mockHelpers);
    });
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as it seems, the sinon stub was not doing what I expected. The test passes now:

```
beforeEach( 
    function () { 
        mockHelpers = { getApiUrl: function(){ return 'testApiUrl/';} }; 
        module('app',function($provide) {$provide.constant('helpers', mockHelpers);}); 
    }
);
```